# Access Multi form data fill

Tags: forms, auto, transfer

I am trying to place a name and address into a form and have it autofill on 3 different tables.
Is this possible?
I have all the tables made with forms. I just don't want to retype it every time.
I am new at access so need a little insight on this.
Thank you.